# Implementing compass

Tags: spring, compass-lucene

Hi
I have to integrate Compass with the Spring. First I thougth to implement the Compass using its core apis, I have also read the documentation
but i am not getting some application from where i can learn the process to implement.
Can any one provide some links to applications to learn the implementation.

Thanks

Comment: If the docs aren't enough, why do you think we'll be able to do any better? At least show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the 2.2.0 version. The zip file has a samples directory and there are complete examples of compass configuring with spring. I have also provided sample config and code at my wiki [here](http://aravind.wikidot.com/sample-code)

Honestly, compass is dead now. there is no support anymore. If you are starting a new project then I suggest you look at [Hibernate Search](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/search.html) or [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.com/) (from the same guy who created compass)